# A word which contains the concept of both Tags and Category?

Tags: web, wording, concept

I have a page which represents all posts based on filtering in *category* and *tag(s)*.

As you know, each post has one category and multiple (or one) tag(s). Now I'm talking about a page which lists all posts that have specific category and/or tag(s).

My question is, what title *(preferably one word)* do you recommend as the title of that page?

Here are my thoughts: *(I don't like them though)*

- filtering
- branches
- advanced list (however this is wrong, because it's two words)
- ct (stands for Category and Tags)

Comment: The difference between categories and tags (as I know the terms) is not that an article has exactly one of​ the former and any number of the latter, but that the former are predefined and hierarchical, the latter free-form and flat.

Comment: "each post has one category" - not necessarily. A post can fall under multiple categories. The difference between categories and tags is simply that categories can be nested, while tags are un-hierarchical.

Comment: How do users get to this page? Do they select a category from a list which takes them to a page of posts filtered by category? If so, do they then filter by tags by choosing them from a list?

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the category page, label it with the name of the category.

If the user clicked on a tag, open the search results page and label it with "Search Results for [tag name]".

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use "Taxonomy"?

> **Taxonomy** a classification into ordered categories:

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/taxonomy

> Taxonomies are different from metadata in that a taxonomy helps you to organize your content and assets into hierarchical relationships. Classifying content and assets in a taxonomy can make it far easier to search for or browse

http://www.dpci.com/insights/taxonomy-vs-metadata

Particularly if the tags typically all fall under the given category thus creating a hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick thought: I think google uses "label" in the mail application. this seems like a intuitive and reasonable choice.

Comment: I 'd go with Labeled.   To signify that the items have been tagged.

Answer (score 1):

I think "Categories and tags" would be the least confusing title.

If you really want a one-word title, I'd suggest "Browse".

Using words like "branches" (or "groups" or "collections" or whatever) makes it sound like you're introducing a whole new concept separate from tags and categories, so I'd recommend against it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though each of your posts is in exactly one category, and can have multiple tags. If that's the case, naming the page with the category name, and displaying the tags used to filter the posts below the category name could work.

[image]

Notice that in addition to having the page named  and the tags used to filter underneath (if applied) and down the side (if not yet applied), there's a breadcrumb that clearly shows the user where they are in the blog hierarchy.

It's common to call posts in a category an "Archive", for example, "ThingsThatAreBetterWithChocolate Archive", though I've always found it to be extraneous.